# How to get conditional formationg of cell in Excel file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a xlsx-file that already has several conditional formatting rules.
How can I get formatting rules from the cell? 
I want to "read" all rules from existing cell and apply them to new ones, that I'll create

Thank you!

```
SheetConditionalFormatting rules = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting(); 
Cell cell = sheet.createRow(18).createCell(1); 
CellReference cr = new CellReference(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex()); 
CellRangeAddress[] range = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B19")};
ConditionalFormatting rule = rules.getConditionalFormattingAt(0);
rules.addConditionalFormatting(range, rule.getRule(0));
```

But I want be able to do smth like that:

```
cell.getFormattingRules();
```

---

I found answer. When I got all rules in the sheet, I can get range of this rules. And now I need to check, is my cell in this range or not.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Share with us... what you have tried till now...

Comment: <code>SheetConditionalFormatting rules = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
Cell cell = sheet.createRow(18).createCell(1);
CellReference cr = new CellReference(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex());
CellRangeAddress[] range = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B19")};
ConditionalFormatting rule = rules.getConditionalFormattingAt(0); rules.addConditionalFormatting(range, rule.getRule(0));
<code>

Comment: But its really not that thing I want to do.
But I dont have another ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirements and I solved it with a couple of functions. Let me know if you find any bugs in it.

It will "copy" the conditional formatting style from the "styleCell" to the "cell"

```
    private void expandConditionalFormatting(XSSFCell cell, XSSFCell styleCell){
      XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting xscf = cell.getSheet().getSheetConditionalFormatting();
      for(int idx = 0;idx<xscf.getNumConditionalFormattings();idx++){
         XSSFConditionalFormatting cf = xscf.getConditionalFormattingAt(idx);
         List<CellRangeAddress> cra = Arrays.asList(cf.getFormattingRanges());
         List<CellRangeAddress> newCra = new ArrayList();
         for(CellRangeAddress c:cra){
            if(containsCell(c, styleCell) && !containsCell(c,cell)){
               newCra.add(new CellRangeAddress(Math.min(c.getFirstRow(), cell.getRowIndex()),Math.max(c.getLastRow(),cell.getRowIndex()),Math.min(c.getFirstColumn(), cell.getColumnIndex()),Math.max(c.getLastColumn(),cell.getColumnIndex())));
            } else{
               newCra.add(c);
            }
         }
         ArrayList<XSSFConditionalFormattingRule> cfs = new ArrayList();
         for(int ci=0;ci<cf.getNumberOfRules();ci++){
            cfs.add(cf.getRule(ci));
         }

         xscf.addConditionalFormatting(newCra.toArray(new CellRangeAddress[newCra.size()]),cfs.toArray(new XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[cfs.size()]));
         xscf.removeConditionalFormatting(idx);
      }
   }
   private boolean containsCell(CellRangeAddress cra, Cell cell){
      if(cra.getFirstRow()<=cell.getRowIndex() && cra.getLastRow()>=cell.getRowIndex()){
         if(cra.getFirstColumn()<=cell.getColumnIndex() && cra.getLastColumn()>=cell.getColumnIndex()){
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Zilom! Actually, after few days of searching for "convinient" way, I implement the similar solution, but forgot to share it here

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this example,
You can have a different approche to expand formula like bellow :
**You have to know exactly the range of orgin formula**

```
private void expandConditionalFormatting(XSSFSheet sheet, CellRangeAddress cellRangeSourceAddress,
        CellRangeAddress cellRangeDestinationAddress) {
    XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting conditions = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < conditions.getNumConditionalFormattings(); idx++) {
        XSSFConditionalFormatting cf = conditions.getConditionalFormattingAt(idx);
        List<CellRangeAddress> cra = Arrays.asList(cf.getFormattingRanges());
        List<CellRangeAddress> newCra = new ArrayList<CellRangeAddress>();
        for (CellRangeAddress c : cra) {
            if (cellRangeSourceAddress.getFirstColumn() == c.getFirstColumn()
                    && cellRangeSourceAddress.getLastColumn() == c.getLastColumn()
                    && cellRangeSourceAddress.getFirstRow() == c.getFirstRow()
                    && cellRangeSourceAddress.getLastRow() == c.getLastRow()) {
                newCra.add(cellRangeDestinationAddress);
            } 
        }
        ArrayList<XSSFConditionalFormattingRule> cfs = new ArrayList<XSSFConditionalFormattingRule>();
        for (int ci = 0; ci < cf.getNumberOfRules(); ci++) {
            cfs.add(cf.getRule(ci));
        }
        if (newCra.size() > 0) {
            conditions.addConditionalFormatting(newCra.toArray(new CellRangeAddress[newCra.size()]),
                    cfs.toArray(new XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[cfs.size()]));
            conditions.removeConditionalFormatting(idx);
        }
    }
}
```